# Connecting to a Virtual Box Ubuntu DataStax Cassandra DSE using C# Driver

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I am trying to connect using Datastax C# client driver on a Windows 7 box to DSE Cassandra running on a virtual box (Ubuntu).
Here is my code:

```
Cluster _cluster = Cluster.Builder()
                      .WithPort(9042)
                      .AddContactPoint("192.168.1.136")
                      .Build();
```

I am getting this error : All host tried for query are in error (tried: 192.168.1.136)

I think the problem is that the remote machine (in this case a virtual box) is not accepting the connection.

Has any one connected from c# driver on Windows 7 to a remote Ubuntu running on virtual box ?

Comment: Check the config on your Ubuntu VM, and make sure that your NIC is running in "bridged" mode.

Comment: It is set to bridged mode already.

Comment: Finally figured it out. Set rpc_address: 192.168.1.136 on cassandra.yaml and it works now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Set rpc_address: 192.168.1.136 on cassandra.yaml and it works now.

Comment: +1 this helped me figure out my Cass/VM issues as well.

Comment: Thanks this saved me too